# Can't figure out why the domain of this function is like this?

Tags: functions

[image: function solved]

Now, this is really solved, but i can't exactly understand why x must be ≠-1. I know this has something to do with the denominator being 0 for that value of x; but if we put "-1" in the denominator,doesn't that make the value of the function for "x=-1" >>"-1/3" ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: +1 on the your name Mathador - it's so damn creative I am impressed! Now, you say "If we put -1 in the denominator". And sure, that's fine when you're JUST considering the denominator. However, you are considering the WHOLE function and when you plug $x = -1$ into the whole function, it does NOT exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the function in $x=-1$ is not defined. Plugging in $x=-1$ you obtain $\frac{-1+1}{(-1+1)(-1-2)}$ which would lead to a $\frac{0}{0}$ form, which is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reason why.

First, note that the original function is $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{(x+1)(x-2)}$. And so the function value then when $x=-1$ is undefined. In particular we have $\frac{0}{0}$.

Second point, if you cancel $(x+1)$ in your numerator and denominator you will get a new function $g(x)=\frac{1}{(x-2)}$ with $g(-1)=\frac{-1}{3}$.

But note that $f(x)\not=g(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$. They are only equal when $x\not=-1$.

So you cannot say that $g(-1)=f(-1)$. So the answer really is undefined.